# Install Postfix dovecot with mysql background

Tags: postfix-mta

I have spent about 3 days to install the Postfix, dovecot and mysql on my VPS server. It has been a very frustrating process. I have googled painfully for 3 days and collected the information piece by piece and eventually made this combination work.

Just want to list steps and all configuration files together, hopefully useful for who is also undergoing the painful process.

1. make mysql ready, and create database postfix (or whatever the name you want), create mysql user postfix and grant all privilege to postfix database.

Create the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE virtual_domains (
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE virtual_aliases (
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
domain_id int(11) NOT NULL,
source varchar(100) NOT NULL,
destination varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES virtual_domains(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE virtual_users (
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
domain_id int(11) NOT NULL,
password varchar(32) NOT NULL,
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
maildir varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY email (email),
FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES virtual_domains(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Compile Postfix with mysql support, you should see the bunch of postfix configuration files:

**main.cf**

[root@mail postfix]#postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /var/postfix/usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /var/postfix/usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6 /binddd  
$daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /home
mailq_path = /var/postfix/usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/local/man
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydomain = myspeedshow.com
myhostname = mail.yourdoamin.com
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /var/postfix/usr/bin/newaliases
postscreen_greet_banner = "before smtp banner"
postscreen_greet_wait = 2s
postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = no
postscreen_pipelining_enable = no
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /var/postfix/usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = no
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
                            reject_invalid_hostname,<br>               
                            reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                            reject_unauth_pipelining,      
                            permit_mynetworks,
                            reject_unauth_destination,
                            reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, 
                            reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, 
                            reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net, 
                            reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
                            reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
                            reject_rbl_client dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net,
                            permit<br>
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtputf8_enable = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias- maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

**master.cf**

```
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/libexec/dovecot   /dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

**mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf**

```
user=postfix
password=yourpassword
host=127.0.0.1
dbname=postfix
query=select name from virtual_domains where name='%s'
```

**mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf**

```
user=postfix
password=yourpassword
dbname=postfix
query=select maildir from virtual_users where email='%s'
```

**mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf**

```
user=postfix
password=yourpassword
host=127.0.0.1
dbname=postfix
query=select destination from virtual_aliases where source='%s'
```

The next step is to configure the Dovecot.

**10-auth.conf**

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-sql.conf.ext
comments out all other !include
```

**auth-sql.conf.ext**

```
passdb {
      driver = sql
      args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
 }
 userdb {
      driver = static
      args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%d/%n
}
```

**10-mail.conf**
comments out all mail_location

Here we use Maildir format to store the email in:

```
/var/vmail/domain/user/Maildir/ folder, in virtual_users table, the column maildir should be in the following format 'yourdomain.com/user/Maildir/'
```

If you have not populated the  `virtual_users.maildir` column correctly, the postfix will use mailbox format, which store all mail belong to a domain to a file `/var/vmail/1`.

Comment: I think it happens because postfix use two parameters to get the full Maildir of the user: virtual_mailbox_base and virtual_mailbox_maps.

So, it will store in: `/var/vmail` + what it gets from `virtual_users.maildir`. If `virtual_users.maildir` is empty, postfix delivers in `/var/vmail` (`virtual_mailbox_base`)

Comment: when add email address, need to do the following things:
1.   insert into virtual_domains (name) values ('abc.com')
2. insert into virtual_users (domain_id,password,email,maildir) values(id,'xxx','xxx@abc.com','abc.com/xxx/Maildir/')
3.create folder /var/vmail/abc.com/xxx/Maildir/cur and  /var/vmail/abc.com/xxx/Maildir/new
4. chown vmail.vamil -R Maildir